# I dont know how to make mysqli query work and there are no errors showing

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have this problem with my code. I have a database created in myphpadmin , the program connects to it, but when i try to use mysqli_query it keeps showing "not executed". Can you help me? Maybe i'm missing something

```
<?php
   $mysqli_host='localhost'; $mysqli_user='root'; $mysqli_password='';
   $conexiune=@mysqli_connect($mysqli_host,$mysqli_user,$mysqli_password);
   @mysqli_select_db('materiale',$conexiune);

 if(!$conexiune=@mysqli_connect($mysqli_host,$mysqli_user,$mysqli_password))
    {
    die('cant connect');    
    }
    else
    {
    echo 'connection success<br>';
    }
 if($is_query_run=@mysqli_query('SELECT * FROM `user`',$conexiune))
    {
    echo 'query executed';
    }
    else
    {
    echo 'not executed' ;   
    }
```

?>

I need to fetch the information from the database bot it will not work if the query isn't working

Comment: Of course there are no errors showing.  You're *suppressing errors*.  Remove all of the error suppression operators, and check your PHP logs, and check for errors with `mysqli_error`, and debug to ensure your code is executing at all.  When you do these things, what specifically is failing?

Comment: Sorry if i'm being difficult it's my first day using mysqli.      I made some changes to get rid of the errors that eventually showed after deleting the @. No errors showing now.    The thing is I dont know why it displays the "not executed" message when i'm checking if the query runs. When i check the connection it shows the "connection soccess" message so that means the connection is working right?

Comment: [How to enable MySQLi exception mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439)

Comment: You need to forget about existence of error suppression operator `@` as a beginner. Errors and warnings are your friend. To learn [how to connect to MySQLi try this tutorial](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/mysqli_connect). I would recommend to learn PDO instead, because it has simpler syntax and is more powerful.

Comment: @AlexandraGhezea: If it’s showing “not executed” then it seems that the query is failing.  You need to use mysqli_error($conexiune) to get the error from the database.

Comment: I used mysqli_error but it's showing 0 errors

Answer (score 0):

Try remove the `@` before the command  .. in PHP  `@`disable the error message

```
 $conexiune=mysqli_connect($mysqli_host,$mysqli_user,$mysqli_password);
```

..

```
 if(!$conexiune=mysqli_connect($mysqli_host,$mysqli_user,$mysqli_password))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your parameter order is wrong, `mysqli_query()` expects the connection handle returned by ´mysqli_connect()` as the first parameter, and the actual query as 2nd parameter, when using the procedural call style.

Looks as if you are mixing parameter semantics of the old, deprecated `mysql` extension with that of the more modern `mysqli` one. Or maybe you are trying to port old code that used `mysql` functions to `mysqli` by just adding the extra `i`?

In old `mysql` the connection handle parameter was optional, and usually the last parameter to be passed when given. This turned out to be a maintenance nightmare over time, and the concept of having a hidden default connection handle was also somewhat questionable.

So there was a clear cut when the new `mysqli` API was introduced with PHP 5 in 2004, making the connection handle the mandatory first parameter, instead of optional last one, and also adding an object oriented API in addition to the classic procedural one.

PS: also, as mentioned by others already, when trying to track down an error, it is not necessarily the best idea to silence warning and error messages with the `@` prefix when calling a function ...

Comment: Im trying to make something for school and all i have are old courses from when we "learned" mysql 2 years ago

Comment: I changed the order and i have no errors now. But i'm still confused about why the query is not executing

Comment: Ok, the next step then would be to check for mysql protocol level error messages. Replace `echo 'not executed' ;` with `echo 'error: '.mysqli_error($conexiune);`

See also https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php